# Can browse to WebDav via browser, but not map to a drive

Tags: apache-http-server, webdav

We can browse to our webdav site using a browser, and it asks for the username and password as normal, but we can't seem to map a drive to it or use a client to access it.

Using a client called "Web Drive", this is the error we get:

> Connecting to domain.com/sites
>
> Resolving url domain.com to an IP address
>
> Url resolved to IP address ***.***.***.***
>
> Connecting to ***.***.***.*** on port 80
>
> Connected successfully to the server on port 80
>
> Testing directory listing ...
>
> Unable to connect to server, error information below
>
> Error: HTTP Error response received from server, erorr=500 (4516)
>
> Operation: Connecting to server
>
> Server Response: 500 Internal Server Error
>
> Connecting to domain.com/sites
>
> Resolving url domain.com to an IP address
>
> Url resolved to IP address ***.***.***.***
>
> Connecting to ***.***.***.*** on port 80
>
> Connected successfully to the server on port 80
>
> Testing directory listing ...
>
> Unable to connect to server, error information below
>
> Error: HTTP Error response received from server, erorr=500 (4516)
>
> Operation: Connecting to server
>
> Server Response: 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the Apache logs, which told me it was having problems opening the "DavLockDB". I checked the dav config file and I noticed I had commented this out.

For those confused by the DavLockDB, it is a database of all the files currently being edited. This prevents anyone else accessing a file that is already being used.